# Due to roach infestations in the past, i began feeding my cat on paper on the dining table. Now she won't eat from her dish again post-bugs

Tags: training, psychology

I have been feeding my senior cat on the kitchen table for a while since I was having problems with roaches getting into her bowl. Now i bought a brand new feeder but she still looks for her food on he table. I've tried adding in treats as a lure like I did on the table but it doesn't seem to be working. i have trued moving the entire dis to the table as a sort of stopgap measure but thus far it's no help either.

Comment: @ the close-vote: if there is a need for more details and clearity, why did you not ask first? (Is there something I missed?)

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the food back step-by step. First, you might put the bowl on the table, some paper on the dish, and the food on the paper, until she gets used to that. Then you can try making the paper smaller, a little each day, until there's none left.

Once she's used to eating out of the dish (on the table) try moving it a little each day. You might move it to the edge of the table, then on top of a chair, then down to the floor (but still next to the table). Eventually you should be able to get the food back to where it was.